# How to remove Bitdefender root certificate from Firefox/Thunderbird/Chrome

Tags: man-in-the-middle, certificate-authority, anti-virus

I'm using "Bitdefender Antivirus Free Edition 1.0.9.54" on my Windows 10 home PC
Antimalware Engine 7.73769

During the last days I got a popup which asked me to shutdown Firefox/Thunderbird/Chrome in order to install "Bitdefender Root Certificate"

This sounds much like a mand-in-the-middle approach to analyze my SSL web traffic: a feature I never asked and which I never accepted to install.
I've opened the antivirus console and there's no option to disable this feature.

Above all I don't see this root certificate in the Firefox (56.0.2 x64) authorities.

I would like to:

- 1) disable at all the web traffic inspector
- 2) uninstall the root certificate from all the browsers

so question is:

- How to disable web scanning in this antivirus which has a minimal GUI
- how to find and remove this certificate from Firefox (and other systems): I already looked at the secriuty settings and there's nothing like "Bitdefender Root Certificate" authority

Answer (score 6):

This is a copy/paste from my post on reddit (https://www.reddit.com/r/BitDefender/comments/7bxixp/install_bitdefender_root_certificate_popup/)

How to get rid of Bitdefender Free edition certificate mess in Firefox (Windows 10, Firefox 57.0.2, Bitdefender FREE antivirus)

1- Check if https://unsplash.com is hijacked and certified by BitDefender

2- Uninstall BitDefender Antivirus Free

3- Uninstall BitDefender Agent

3- Reboot Computer

4- Start Firefox Check https://unsplash.com -- Should be certified by GlobalSign now

5- Reinstall Bitdefender Antivirus Free - Do NOT close Firefox when asked, just cancel BitDefender Root certificate installation

6- Let Bitdefender finish its installation.

7- Reload unsplash.com, another popup should appear, and cancel again the Bitdefender certificate installation.

8- From now, your Firefox should be immune to BitDefender certificate (close and restart then reload unsplash.com to be sure).

9- For extra Windows cleanup, remove the Bitdefender certifcate using certificate manager.

10- You can check residual rogue certificates in windows with sigcheck from SysInternals ( 'sigcheck -tv' in a console)

No side effects noticed yet.

Enjoy.

Comment: This works for Firefox. Has anyone found a solution for Chrome (i.e. disable the SSL sniffing without disabling Bitdefender entirely)? Deleting the root certificate just breaks SSL sites completely.

Comment: Why is this a "mess", why not just allow Bitdefender to do its thing?

Comment: How exactly do you do step 1? And what do you do differently if the answer is Yes vs. No.

Comment: I figure you already found it, @Mick but you just check the certificate of the page, though that domain is not a valid test for me, it's never overtaken by bitdefender.. VISA home _is_ getting intercepted though O.o